# How applying a function to multiple lists and get a list as the output in R?

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply, mapply

I have two lists **A** and **B** that each of which has 100 elements. Each element is a square matrix, *N* in *N*. I want to multiply element *i* in list **A** with element *i* in list **B** (I between 1 and 100) and having a list of 100 elements as the output.

How I can do that with apply functions? e.g., *lapply*, *sapply*, *mapply*, ...

Comment: Have you tried `Map(\`*\`, A, B)` ?

Comment: you don't need to use functionals just `as.list(A*B)` but why do you want to have result as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RonakShah said in the comment, `Map` is likely the answer here.

Think of it this way: `lapply` applies a function to each element of one list:

```r
myfunc <- function(x) {
  # do something with x
}
lapply(1:4, myfunc)
## unrolls to be the equivalent of ...
list(
  myfunc(1),
  myfunc(2),
  myfunc(3),
  myfunc(4)
)
```

`Map`, however, "zips" each `n`th element of multiple lists together. The equivalent of the above `lapply` using `Map` is

```r
Map(myfunc, 1:4)
```

but there is a lot more.

```r
myfunc_many <- function(x, y, z) {
  # do something with all three args
}
Map(myfunc_many, 1:4, 11:14, 21:24)
## unrolls to 
list(
  myfunc_many(1, 11, 21),
  myfunc_many(2, 12, 22),
  myfunc_many(3, 13, 23),
  myfunc_many(4, 14, 24)
)
```

`Map` can deal with an arbitrary number of lists; if your function is [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) (accepts arbitrary number of arguments), it will still work (though your function has to have built-in mechanisms for dealing with that, making it variadic):

```r
myfunc_variadic <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  # do something with dots
}
Map(myfunc_variadic, 1:4)
Map(myfunc_variadic, 1:4, 11:14)
Map(myfunc_variadic, 1:4, 11:14, 21:24, 31:34, 41:44)
```

In all of the examples above, I've used vectors as each argument, but it works just as well with lists of things. As a final example,

```r
set.seed(42)
L1 <- replicate(2, matrix(sample(6), nrow = 2), simplify = FALSE)
L2 <- replicate(2, matrix(sample(6), nrow = 2), simplify = FALSE)
L1
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    6    2
# [2,]    5    4    3
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    1    5
# [2,]    6    3    4
L2
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    4    5    3
# [2,]    1    2    6
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    1    5
# [2,]    3    4    6
Map(`*`, L1, L2)
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    4   30    6
# [2,]    5    8   18
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    4    1   25
# [2,]   18   12   24
```